# trouble with GD and Drupal

Tags: drupal, debian, gd

I changed my website from another VM (for dev). I have this error

```
Drupal\Component\Plugin\Exception\PluginNotFoundException: The "" plugin does not exist. Valid plugin IDs for Drupal\Core\ImageToolkit\ImageToolkitManager are: gd in Drupal\Core\Plugin\DefaultPluginManager->doGetDefinition() (line 53 of core/lib/Drupal/Component/Plugin/Discovery/DiscoveryTrait.php).
```

But GD is installed. :/

```
root@debian:/var/log/apache2# php -i | grep 'GD'
GD Support => enabled
GD headers Version => 2.2.5
GD library Version => 2.2.4
```

Have you an idea?

Thanks

Comment: go to admin/reports - site report , check what it says. I think it's not a lack of GD, but some misconfiguration. As an alternative you can install imagick module https://www.drupal.org/project/imagemagick and see if it solves your problem.

Comment: Check what phpinfo() says. console php setup can be different than web one.